# React Native conditional style based on mapped array field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to create list with an altered style based on selection:

I have a dynamic state -

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      inventoryArray: InvData.map(obj => ({...obj, clicked: false})),
    }
  }
```

I want to use the clicked state of each object to determine styling - but am not quite sure on th syntax to use  - i've tried:

```
 returnInventoryObjects = () => {

    return (

      this.state.inventoryArray.map((data, i) => {
        return (
          if({data.clicked}) ? {
            <View key={i} style={[InventoryStyles.InventoryItem,  InventoryStyles.InventoryItemSel ]}>
          }
          else{
            <View key={i} style={[InventoryStyles.InventoryItem]}>
          }
```

which doesn't work -

I've also tried an inline dynamic style ie -

```
returnInventoryObjects = () => {

    return (

      this.state.inventoryArray.map((data, i) => {
        return (
      
          <View key={i} style={[InventoryStyles.InventoryItem,  {data.clicked} &&  InventoryStyles.InventoryItemSel ]}>
```

Can anyone please advise how to achieve this please?

Heres the error shown when implementing option 2 -

[image]

Styles used are:

```
InventoryItem:{
    backgroundColor:'rgba(255,255,255,0.8)',
    paddingVertical:8,
    paddingHorizontal:8,
    flexDirection:'row',
    marginBottom:15,
  },
  InventoryItemSel:{
    backgroundColor:'rgba(255,255,255,0.2)',
  },
```

Comment: Can you add the styles you are using? The code you posted seems to be ok

Comment: thanks for trying to help @BastianE.  Though the errors displayed are syntax related rather than style - styles work without the contional logic (have added above anyhow)

Comment: Oh I see, and how does the parent element looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you tried to make conditional style like so:

```
<View
  key={i}
  style={
    data.clicked
      ? [InventoryStyles.InventoryItem]
      : [InventoryStyles.InventoryItem, InventoryStyles.InventoryItemSel]
  }
/>
```

I would do:

```
// More maintanable
const DEFAULT = [InventoryStyles.InventoryItem];

<View
  style={
    data.clicked ? DEFAULT : [...DEFAULT, InventoryStyles.InventoryItemSel]
  }
/>
```

Notice that the statement `{data.clicked}` is parsed as an expression within scope, and not as an object or something else that you meant.

So using it within an array or in `if` expression, is an syntax error.

```
{ // Scope
  data.clicked // Expression
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
this.state.inventoryArray.map((data, i) => {
      if(data.clicked) {
          return (
            <View key={i} style={[InventoryStyles.InventoryItem,  InventoryStyles.InventoryItemSel ]} />
          )
      }
      else {
          return (
              <View key={i} style={[InventoryStyles.InventoryItem]} />
          )
      }
}
```

Comment: You've missed / at the end of the View component: 
<View />

Comment: not that - i only showed a segment of the view above - it error on the if statement line.  Thanks for your help anyway.  cheers

Answer (score -1):

React components that don't have children need to be self-closing (/ at the end). Notice the difference between

```
<View key={i} style={[InventoryStyles.InventoryItem,  InventoryStyles.InventoryItemSel ]}>
```

and

```
<View key={i} style={[InventoryStyles.InventoryItem,  InventoryStyles.InventoryItemSel ]} />
```

Be sure to correct this in all your `View` components
The rest looks fine!